# Rails - AMS - Add key to every json response from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm updating my Rails app to active_model_serializers 0.10.4 but I'm having trouble updating a necessary feature: the ability to add request information to every json response from the controller.

In AMS 0.9.x I used to do it by using [default_serializer_options](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-9-stable/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb#L74) but that funcionality is gone, and apparently the only way to achieve this is manually adding the `meta` key to EVERY request.

Has anyone found a workaround to make this work?

Comment: Hey! I'm still using AMS 0.9.x and trying to achieve the same functionality. Can you please tell me how you modified the default_serializer_options method to add meta key to every request? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb` file add this line:

`ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json`

The example below will add a data attribute at the top level, and render the `@users` objects under `data` key in your response.

In your controller:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users, root: "data"
  end
```

If you're going for a JSON API schema with a meta tag and a data tag with objects for every response, simply change initializer to

`ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api`

and controller to

```
 def index
    @users = User.all
    @extra_meta = {"totalCount": @users.size}

    render json: @users, root: "data", meta: default_meta_attributes(@users, @extra_meta)
  end
```

In my case default_meta_attributes is in the base controller and merges in some details about the request like current_user_id, etc with the option to add additional details in each method

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a more specific example of what you're trying to do?  You could make an ApplicationSerializer and set the serialization_scope to `:view_context` then do whatever you want in the serializer. You could also customize the JSON adapter.  Or, if you want, you can prepend a module to SerializableResource to add options.